# How to Send Jquery Ajax data on Same php Page?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

hi i want to send javascript data via ajax to the same page in wordpress. Cannot fetch the data in testajax.php page. its shows Undefined index: name. And how to send the data on same php page rather than testajax.php ?

```
<script>
jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'http://localhost/projects/xxx/wordpress/wp-content/themes/xxx/testajax.php',
                data: {name:'foo'},
                success: function(data)
                {
                    alert('success');
                }
            });
```

Comment: I don't see the URL... Where are you sending your data ? Maybe this is the problem...

Comment: I hope u r still adapting to AJAX. This is completely wrong. you have to have a url provided..

Comment: What does your console say?

Comment: Everyone... a blank URL means it submits to the same page, as OP wants.

Comment: Please provide more code. Have you tried using Chrome's Developer Tools (F12) to check for Javascript syntax?

Comment: edited.. Still cant get the work done.

Comment: @user2725420 Please add more details to your question and explain what you have tried.

Answer (score 4):

```
var foo = 'somename';
jQuery.ajax({
    url:'yourUrl',
    type: "POST",
    data: {'name':foo},
    success: function(data)
        {
           alert('success');
        }
});
```

php

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['name'])){
      //Do whatever you want
   }else{
      //Do whatever you want
   }
```

?>

Comment: Your missing a ) in the php isset

Comment: @웃웃웃웃웃 Can you not leave the url field empty?

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery.ajax({
   url: "./_FILE_" // ./index.php for example
   type: "POST",
   data: {name:'foo'},
   success: function(data)
   {
      alert('success');
   }
});
```

Comment: BUt is there a way to get the data on the same page itself ?

Comment: For this I will need to know how you call your page, the url of your form and what techno / FW you're using

Comment: i am not using a <form>. i use a table. with few input tags. and gather the data onclick event. i can store the data in javascript variable. but cannot send that data using ajax.

Comment: You should edit your post and add your HTML file plus the link of those, that would help me / us

Comment: <li>
              <fieldset>
              <label>Total Weight(KG) :</label>
              <input type="text" name="total_weight" id="total_weight" value="" />
              </fieldset>
            </li>
            <li class="last">
              <fieldset>
              <input type="button" name="button" value="Check" class="Check" onclick="calculate();" />
              </fieldset>
            </li>

Comment: function calculate()
{var tot_wt = $("#total_weight").val();}

Comment: Your page is a index.php?
Or a rest route?

Comment: no its not an index.php page. its a page inside the theme section of wordpress folder.

Comment: Ok and what is the URL of your page then, so I can give you the URL field for your ajax query haha

Comment: its a page.php , and its located in the same folder as the testajax.php is located in wordpress folder

Comment: Ok, but wordpress is lead by a rewritting URL system which means that you can't do that like this. But with wordpress you have a function to get in which page you have in PHP.

Then you can add it to your javascript by <?php echo __Your_Function__; ?>

Comment: how to post the ajax data on same page and store it in a php variable Or Session ?